# What is meant by Multi-Cloud Clustering? Can anyone help me in understanding it in detail? Any helpful articles will be highly appreciated

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cluster, cloud, failovercluster

Can someone help me in understanding what Multi-Cloud Clustering is? How can it be done and which are the best options for Multi-Cloud Clustering in the market today? Thanks.

Comment: https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/a-multi-cloud-and-multi-cluster-architecture-with-kubernetes_595541

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! At first have a look at the [How do I ask a good question?](https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, please check [Introducing Anthos: An entirely new platform for managing applications in today's multi-cloud world](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/hybrid-cloud/new-platform-for-managing-applications-in-todays-multi-cloud-world). Please update your question with more details about your use case and goals.

Answer (score 1):

Multi-Cloud Clustering means making use of various Cloud Computing and Storage Services under a single system architecture. It consists of more than one cloud vendor which can be either public or private.

Please refer to this link for more information about Multi-Cloud Clustering:

https://www.openminds.co.uk/blogs/multi-cloud-clustering/